# jquery validate not unhighlighting when radio button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I have a form with a radio button group which is inside a **fieldset** with a **data-role=controlgroup**. I am using the **jQuery Mobile** and jQuery Validate plugins to handle presentation and form validation. The problem I'm having is that the unhighlight method I have defined is not getting called after the sequence where submit button is clicked causing the validation to show errors, and then subsequently a radio button is clicked.

My Validate setup is like this:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page", function() {

  $(".product_type_form").validate({
      validClass: "data-valid", 
      errorClass: "data_invalid",
      errorElement: "span",                     
      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
          if ($(element).is("input[type='radio']")) {
              container = $(element).parents('div.ui-controlgroup-controls');
          } else {
              container = $(element).parents('div.ui-input-text');
          }             
          error.insertBefore(container);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).is("input[type='radio']")) {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-controlgroup-controls');    
        } else {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-input-text');
        }
        container.addClass(errorClass);
        container.removeClass(validClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).is("input[type='radio']")) {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-controlgroup-controls');    
        } else {
            container = $(element).parents('div.ui-input-text');
        }            
        container.addClass(validClass);
        container.removeClass(errorClass);            
    }         
  });    
});
```

I looked at the jQuery plugin docs for Validate and noticed this:

> onclick
>
> Type: Boolean or Function()
>
> Validate checkboxes and radio buttons on click. Set to false to disable.

I understood this to mean that the default for it was true (it is enabled), so why does my highlight method not get called for the radio button onclick events?

The page can be seen [here](https://www.dealdirectfinancial.co.uk/index.php?option=com_diymobile&task=TestForm1.showForm).

Tried to set up a Fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickweavers/QxLMC/) but couldn't make it work :(

TIA

Comment: I created a new validation method called radio_group as I couldn't get required to work for radio groups as I wanted. 
Also created a rule and message map. These have improved behavior but the thing I'm have had the most trouble with is understanding why event triggers such as “on key up” during data entry, “on blur” of the field, and “on click” of the submit button are all caught and acted upon by validate, but radio button clicks aren't? I want my new radio_group method not just to get called when  the submit button is clicked, but also when a radio button is clicked, or a text input blurs.

Comment: You are correct... `radio` buttons are validated when they're clicked.  **Please show us the relevant HTML markup** in the OP.  Never rely on external links/demos for that.

Comment: In your jsFiddle, your HTML attributes are very sloppy... almost half of them are missing quotation marks.

Comment: I started working on your jsFiddle and then I quit because I ended up doing much of what should have already been done.  The best way to present a problem here is with _just enough code_ that reproduces the issue.  In other words, we don't need the CSS or the full form markup (_I'm not going through all that code to add back the quotation marks you left out._)  See: http://sscce.org

Comment: The output is in Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickweavers/QxLMC/12/) and works more or less as it does on my server (although the styling is a bit off for some reason). Feel free to fork it and mod. I have tidied up the bits that upset you and taken out most of the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Let's be clear about something... I am not "upset".  I am trying to guide you so that your question become more answerable... and therefore becomes more useful to the community as well.  BTW - your new jsFiddle has an empty JavaScript frame.  The HTML goes inside the HTML frame and the JavaScript goes inside the JavaScript frame.

Comment: I was having trouble getting it to run with the JS in JS frame. Have moved it back and it seems okay now. http://jsfiddle.net/nickweavers/QxLMC/15/

Comment: All I can tell you is that jQuery Validate is not doing anything in your jsFiddle.  Doesn't appear as if jQuery Mobie is working either.

Comment: Click the Continue button and you will see that Validate is getting involved. If you take out the JS you'll see it reverts to HTML5 validation.

Comment: Nope.  My browser is giving an "uncaught exception" error on jQM.

Comment: Hmm.. Chrome 34.0.1847.116 is at least running validate for the submit click for me. But I agreed that JQM isn't working for me either. I'll investigate.

Comment: I reloaded the external resources and it's looking better for me now. http://jsfiddle.net/nickweavers/QxLMC/17/

Comment: Did you notice that you only have the problem when using jQuery Mobile?  Remove jQM and the `radio` error immediately clears upon clicking a radio button.  You may have to force a workaround.  Trigger the `.valid()` method upon clicking a `radio` button.  `.valid()` will programatically force a validation test.

Comment: Something odd going on with Fiddle. If you use the latest link I gave above you get the latest version with 3 external resources. If you go in via Fiddle's home page it only shows 2 for the same version (it misses the jquery mobile css).

Comment: jsFiddle simply does not yet offer your version of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for spotting that. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, **only** when you use jQuery Mobile, the click event of the `radio` is ignored by the jQuery Validate plugin.

Here is a workaround that programatically triggers a validation test when a radio button is clicked...

```
$('input[name="product_type"]').on('click', function() {
    $(this).valid();  // triggers a validation test
});
```

**Your demo modified**:  http://jsfiddle.net/QxLMC/18/

Comment: Great. Many thanks! Sorry I can't vote up. Only got a rep of 10.

Comment: It looks like jQM wants to handle the radio button click event and present the error as a tooltip. I'm guessing it prevents the event from bubbling after it's caught it so Validate doesn't see it.

Comment: @NickWeavers, AFAIK, there are no tooltips built into jQM.  You're probably seeing the HTML5 validation kick in when jQuery Validate is not initialized.

Comment: @NickWeavers For radio buttons and checkbox, listen to `change` not `click` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/QxLMC/28/

Comment: @Omar, in this case it doesn't matter too much because we're not toggling anything, we're just forcing a validation test.  The plugin will react appropriately if the state was changed.

Comment: I just wanted to share how to properly listen to radio/checkbox changes in jQM.

Answer (score -1):

When manipulating checkboxes/radio buttons via javascript , 'refresh' method needs to be called so as to affect the style. sample below :

```
$("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Comment: This just appears to always set the last radio button to chec ke

Comment: Dont add the attr('checked',true) only chain refresh method

Answer (score -1):

This little code will call your method if any radio button will selected.

and **this** keyword refer to your radio button which one is selected.

```
$('[name$="product_type"]:checked').each(function()
{
   yourmethod(this);
});
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the OP's problem.  The plugin is supposed to already take care of this.